# Networking optimization

Tags: etl

At work we do a lot of ETLs for customers from the data that they give to us. Our networking I think is a little inefficient and I want to talk to our networking admin but I do not know what questions to ask.

One of the longest parts of the ETL is loading the work on a test server from my conversion machine. My ETL machine and test machine are on the same rack, can these machines be connected in some way so when they exchange information it is done over their own private network and doesn't have to travel over our vpn. I want a couple of gigabit cable across these guys, also we have two more machines in that room that are used by my department and if possible I would like to increase this data transfer as well.

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming problem, so it's not suitable for Stack Overflow. In fact, this looks more like a letter to Santa than anything.

Comment: do you have any recommendations of where to find this information, or at least what topic to search

Comment: 10GBit adapters are pretty commonplace now, so that might be an option, but there's also options like [FibreChannel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibre_Channel).